# Validation doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have this model

```
class DishTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :day_id, :price, :quantity, :restaurant_id, :name, :description, :photo, :photo_cache
  validates :name, :presence => true

  mount_uploader :photo, DishPhotoUploader
end
```

And validation works fine in console, but in browser it works strangely. It doesn't save any model without name, but it also doesn't tell me about error, no red border around form, no anything, goes to the list like there is no problem. What can be wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: What does you're view and save action look like? My guess it's in one of those two places somewhere.

Comment: your simply not displaying your errors in your view. @dishtemplate.errors.full_messages.each do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i solved this issue by adding this code to 'create'

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @dish_template.save
    format.html { redirect_to admin_restaurant_dish_templates_path(@restaurant), notice: 'template was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @dish_template, status: :created, location: @dish_template }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @dish_templates.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably removed

```
  <% if @object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@object.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this object from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

From form partial. Place it back.